Leftover cards in phase 2 with Dinosaur hero
The Claim expansion "Reinforcements: Mercenaries" contains hero cards, including the Dinosaur card which states

In Phase 2, if this card is defeated then you can add it back into your hand.

Does this mean the player has additional hand cards at the end of Phase 2? Are those simply omitted from the scoring, or do they count as extra cards for that player?

What game is this about?

@JoeW it's Claim, there's no tag yet and I can't make one.

I've added links to the publisher's page.

Thanks, I have added a tag for the game.
